# Create a Symbolic Link from Windows to WSL with a Local Admin Account

Tags: linux, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I am trying to share a config file between windows and wsl/linux.

The file is in wsl/linux and I want to link to it from windows.

This is the command I am trying with a local admin account:

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path ".\.config\nvim" -Target "\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\username\.config\nvim"
```

But that throws this error:

```
New-Item : Cannot find path '\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\username\.config\nvim' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path ".\.config\nvim" -Target "\\wsl ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\username\.config\nvim:String) [New-Item], ItemNotFound
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

The local admin account does not see the wsl directory.

My user account sees it

```
cd "\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\username\.config\nvim"
pwd

Path
----
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\username\.config\nvim
```

How can I create the symbolic-link without making my user account an admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that PowerShell is running without administrative privileges and utilize the `mklink` command in the following format.

```
cmd /c mklink /D "C:\Users\YourUsername\.config\nvim" "\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\username\.config\nvim"
```

### Supporting Resource

- [mklink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html)

  > **Elevation**
  >
  > By default, only Administrators can create symbolic links. The
  > security setting 'Create symbolic links' can be granted at:
  > `Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\`
  >
  > Creating a symbolic link requires elevation, but from `Windows 10 build 14972`, *symlinks can be created without needing to elevate the
  > console* as administrator - **this does however require that you have
  > Developer Mode enabled.**